# Nexus Site Repository: Can I use SCP?

Tags: maven, nexus, maven-site-plugin

We run a Nexus 2.14 with a site repository. At the moment, we deploy the sites using DAV, which is at times quite a burden for the server because a lot of small files are transferred separately.

SCP would probably be a better alternative, but I found no information whether this is supported by Nexus and if so, what I need to do to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Sonatype support told that this is not possible.